# How does list slicing hook into __getitem__?

Tags: python, list, slice, python-2.x, magic-methods

```
>>> class List(list):
...     def __getitem__(self, i):
...         print i, type(i)
...         return super(List, self).__getitem__(i)
...     
>>> x = List([0,1,2,3])
>>> x[1:3:]
slice(1, 3, None) <type 'slice'>
[1, 2]
>>> x[1:3]
[1, 2]
```

Why the second case doesn't use `List.__getitem__`?  What does it use instead?

```
>>> x[::]
slice(None, None, None) <type 'slice'>
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> x[:]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Same again, why discrepancy here aren't these both slicing operations?

Comment: btw this was v2.7.6 so `__getslice__` is (allegedly) deprecated

Comment: FYI Can't re-create in 3.4.0 (i.e. I get `slice(1, 3, None) <type 'slice'>` for both cases).

Comment: yes py3 behaves sanely

Comment: FWIW, since it's a subclass, you can make it consistent by defining `__getslice__ = lambda self, i, j: self.__getitem__(slice(i, j))`.

Comment: and `__delslice__`, and `__setslice__` , and the version info check for < 2.0 ... bleh  :0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__) says it all.  Specifically:

> > > *Deprecated since version 2.0* : Support slice objects as parameters `__getitem__()` method. (However, built-in types in CPython currently still implement `__getslice__()`. **Therefore, you have to override it in derived classes when implementing slicing.**)

and:

> > > Called to implement evaluation of **self[i:j]** ...

Note it doesn't handle `self[i:j:]` ...

Comment: does that mean you have to handle slices in _both_ getslice and getitem? annoying ..

Comment: Yep, that's what it means -- but only for subclasses of builtin types.  Fortunately, it's as easy as `def __getslice__(self, i, j):  return self[i:j:None]` or `self.__getitem__(slice(i, j))` if you prefer to be a little more explicit about it...

Comment: @downvoter -- If you leave a comment about how this is incorrect or unclear, I'd be happy to try to address your issues and improve this answer :-)

Comment: @glglgl -- Thanks for the edits.  I was copy/pasting too quickly :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the section from the [python2.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#index-36) that describes how slicings work:

> The slicing now selects all items with index k such that i <= k < j where i and j are the specified lower and upper bounds.

Comment: I don't think this is what @wim was asking about ...